# Not getting full profile while trying to import data from linkedIn using oAuth 2

Tags: ios, iphone, oauth-2.0, linkedin-api

I'm building an app and using linkedIn oAuth2.0 for authentication and getting user's profile data but somehow I'm not able to get full profile info of the user. I'm using iOSLinkedInAPI library for authentication.

Here is my code.

```
    - (void)viewDidLoad
    {
        NSArray *grantedAccess = @[@"r_fullprofile", @"r_network", @"r_emailaddress"];

        NSString *clientId = @"client_id"; 
        NSString *clientSecret = @"clientSecret"; 
        NSString *state = @"state"; 
        LIALinkedInApplication *application = [LIALinkedInApplication applicationWithRedirectURL:@"linkedin_login_redirect_url" clientId:clientId clientSecret:clientSecret state:state grantedAccess:grantedAccess];
        self.client = [LIALinkedInHttpClient clientForApplication:application];
}


-(IBAction)linkedInButtonClicked:(id)sender
{
    NSLog(@"did press login");
    [self.client getAuthorizationCode:^(NSString *code) {
        [self.client getAccessToken:code success:^(NSDictionary *accessTokenData) {
            NSString *accessToken = [accessTokenData objectForKey:@"access_token"];
            NSLog(@"%@",accessToken);
            [self.client GET:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~?oauth2_access_token=%@&format=json", accessToken] parameters:nil success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSDictionary *result) {
                NSLog(@"current user %@", result);
            }            failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
                NSLog(@"failed to fetch current user %@", error);
            }];
        }                   failure:^(NSError *error) {
            NSLog(@"Quering accessToken failed %@", error);
        }];
    }                          cancel:^{
        NSLog(@"Authorization was cancelled by user");
    }                         failure:^(NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"Authorization failed %@", error);
    }];

}
```

OUTPUT:

I'm even getting this screen.

[image]

```
MyApp[723:60b] current user {
    firstName = XYZ;
    headline = "something at something";
    lastName = XYZ;
    siteStandardProfileRequest =     {
        url = "http://www.linkedin.com/profile/view?id=12345&authType=name&authToken=something";
    };
}
```

Comment: same problem.any suggestions?

Comment: Not yet. I'll post it here once i found the solution.

Comment: Found the solution

- (void)requestMeWithToken:(NSString *)accessToken {
    [self.client GET:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~:(id,first-name,last-name,maiden-name,email-address)?oauth2_access_token=%@&format=json", accessToken] parameters:nil success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSDictionary *result) {
        NSLog(@"current user %@", result);
    }        failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"failed to fetch current user %@", error);
    }];
}

Comment: Can you explain bit more like where i'm going wrong or where i have to use the above code given by you..

Comment: In your 
-(IBAction)linkedInButtonClicked:(id)sender method
you have edit like this
[NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~:(id,first-name,last-name,maiden-name,email-address)?oauth2_access_token=%@&format=json", accessToken]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
- (IBAction)didTapBtn:(id)sender {
    [self.client getAuthorizationCode:^(NSString *code) {
        [self.client getAccessToken:code success:^(NSDictionary *accessTokenData) {
            NSString *accessToken = [accessTokenData objectForKey:@"access_token"];
            [self requestMeWithToken:accessToken];
        }                   failure:^(NSError *error) {
            NSLog(@"Quering accessToken failed %@", error);
        }];
    }                      cancel:^{
        NSLog(@"Authorization was cancelled by user");
    }                     failure:^(NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"Authorization failed %@", error);
    }];
}


- (void)requestMeWithToken:(NSString *)accessToken {
    [self.client GET:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~:(id,first-name,last-name,maiden-name,email-address)?oauth2_access_token=%@&format=json", accessToken] parameters:nil success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSDictionary *result) {
        NSLog(@"current user %@", result);
    }        failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"failed to fetch current user %@", error);
    }];
}


- (LIALinkedInHttpClient *)client {
    LIALinkedInApplication *application = [LIALinkedInApplication applicationWithRedirectURL:@"https://www.example.com"
                                                                                    clientId:@"xxxxxxxxx"
                                                                                clientSecret:@"xxxxxxxxx"
                                                                                       state:@"xxxxxx"
                                                                               grantedAccess:@[@"r_fullprofile",@"r_emailaddress",@"r_network",@"r_contactinfo"]];
    return [LIALinkedInHttpClient clientForApplication:application presentingViewController:nil];
}
```

Comment: Do you know how to share url in linked-in using this library

Comment: you mean to say post something to linkedIn using this ?

Comment: I haven't looked into it but i'll surely give sometime to this n will try help you out.

Comment: https://github.com/pmilanez/MIS-Linkedin-Share
Try using this, It might help you.